# Setting HISTFILE to a named pipe

Tags: python, linux, bash

I have been searching all over for how to do this, and it seems like it's been mentioned a few times as a suggestion, I have yet to find an example.

I tried the following:

```
mkfifo /tmp/testpipe
mknod /tmp/testpipe p
```

Finally I updated my ~/.bashrc file to contain the following:
HISTFILE=/tmp/testpipe

I found a script online that *should* read the pipe this:

```
#!/bin/bash

pipe=/tmp/testpipe

trap "rm -f $pipe" EXIT

if [[ ! -p $pipe ]]; then
    mkfifo $pipe
fi

while true
do
    if read line <$pipe; then
        if [[ "$line" == 'quit' ]]; then
            break
        fi
        echo $line
    fi
done

echo "Reader exiting"
```

I've ran it with a comparable "hello world" that is written to the pipe, and it does display it (so I know the pipe exists, and can receive data).

When I set the bashrc to the above and restart my terminal, I don't get a command prompt until I hit control C twice (Assuming it's trying to write to the named pipe, but I don't have a running script so I can't "read it", so I have to kill it). As I continue it will keep history but that's because it's in ram and not being pushed to the file.

I found this which might have some useful info, but I'm just not sure how to make it work for what I'm trying to do.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/67283/is-it-possible-to-make-writing-to-bash-history-immediate
when I tried entering in some of that in combination with the named pipe, I never got a command prompt. I finally just closed the shell, and commented out those lines.

My ultimate goal is that I'd like to be able to take each command as they are issued, and push them to an online database or something, so I can have something *similar* to web page browsing history, but for commands. It'll tell me what commands I used on each device, dates, and times.

My initial thought is that I might be able to do this through a named pipe, but I don't have a clue if that even would work or makes logical sense.

I was hoping I could setup the named pipe, then startup python or something to read the pipe as it's written to, and push the data online to say firebase or something.

I guess I have a few questions.

1. Is a named pipe even a good idea for this whole thing? (if not do you have any other ideas?)
2. Is there another way to constantly push the data out remotely?

*background: I had installed drivers for a wifi usb dongle on my main pc a few months back, but that PC won't boot right now (power issues I think), I upgraded ubuntu on my netbook (I was running old version that wouldn't update anymore.) and the normal wifi wasn't working, so I plugged in the usb wifi and it works (but is flaky) I know to resolve those issues I had to perform a few other steps, but as it is, now I need to google things (and I don't remember if the recommendations I got were straightforward or not now, or If I had to fiddle). Which brought me to the idea that being able to search history by device over time would be kinda a neat thing to have. I thoguht about downloading the BASH source and injecting something in there and recompiling and using that, but I'd have to do that for each device, it'd be much handier to just toss a few things into the PC at the beginning of the install and be done with it.

*UPDATE IN RESPONSE TO QUESTION/COMMENT
While splitting into different hist files by PID is a good way to delineate the command histories, I'm not sure how to push each command to a remote database each time an update happens, I would almost have to open the pid named file, grab the contents and push to the remote db, and erase the contents while hopefully not blocking the shopt? command from running to store off the next command that occurs (assuming you have a bunch of commands hammer through at a time). Do you have any suggestions whether that would be an issue or not?

Comment: You could set `HISTFILE` to an expression including something unique for each shell, e.g. the pid, then use the solution from that askubuntu page. At that point, you'd have a separate histfile for each shell, which you could query with an external process. Of course, this might also break loading a histfile on new shell; maybe some scheme other than pid is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that there is no simple way to intercept the history the way you would like to do. I have just had a look to bash source, and there are many issues that make almost impossible to replace a plain history file with a pipe:

1) bash READS the history at startup, but of course this can only work if the history is a plain file (unless yor program is really smart and inject character as a fake history - but see the next points). That's probably the reason why your shell hangs.

2) bash limits the file size, so it has to play with services that only apply to plain files (e.g. "truncate", "lseek"...).

3) the way bash handles history depends on its version/build. I wouldn't be surprised if a solution that was used to work on a version stopped working on another one.

Maybe a better solution is monitoring filesystem events in order to detect changes to the history file. Not as simple as listening to a pipe, but if you are interested you can have a look to [inotify API](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify).

Comment: One of the hangups to monitoring to history file updates is that it wouldn't push the history after each command, only when it finally pushes to the history file, I *believe* I read that it will only push when you close your session. Additionally I wouldn't be able to break it down by session (which is really the ideal one, in the event I'm doing different operations in each window). I'll have to keep thinking about ways to work around this.